# Set of subsequences for each sequence of integers is uncountable

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-set-theory

We have a set that contains sequences of integers, so that every sequence of integers has a subsequence that is in this set. Is this uncountable? If so, could you prove it?

I know that set of all sequences of integers is uncountable. 
Now, I want to prove that the set I was taking about, let call it S is uncountable. Let it be countable (proof by contradiction). Know, I don't know how  I should define function from set of natural numbers to this set. This is where I stuck.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. You are more likely to get answers rather than downvotes or votes to close if you edit the question to show us what you tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't go far much.

Comment: To clarify: Let $A=\Bbb N^{\Bbb N}$ be the set of all sequences. For $\alpha,\beta\in A$ say $\alpha\preceq \beta$ if $\alpha$ is a subsequenec of  $\beta$. Now the question is: If $S\subseteq A$ has the property that for every $\beta\in A$ there exists $\alpha\in S$ with $\alpha\preceq\beta$, does this imply that $S$ is uncountable?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I want to say yes, but ... What if S has sequences of length only 1, and it has all integers. For example, (1), (2), (3), ... Then every sequence of integers has a subsequence in S, and S is countable.

Comment: @panpan I suppose that here "sequence" means "infinite sequence"

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Then how can I tell if one infinite sequence is subsequence of another infinite sequence? And how does it imply that S is uncountable? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Lemma.** Let $\mathcal P_\infty(\Bbb N)$ denote the set of all *infinite* subsets of $\Bbb N$.
Suppose $A_1,A_2,A_3,\ldots $ are countably many elements of $\mathcal P_\infty(\Bbb N)$. Then there exists $X\in \mathcal P_\infty(\Bbb N)$ such that $\forall k\in\Bbb N, A_k\not\subseteq X$.

*Proof.*
Let $a_k:=\min\{\,x\in A_k\mid x>2k\,\}$ (possible because $A_k$ is infnite) and $X=\Bbb N\setminus\{\,a_k\mid k\in\Bbb N\,\}$.  Then $X$ is infnite because it lacks at most $n$ of the numbers $\{1,\ldots, 2n\}$. And clearly, $a_k\in A_k\setminus X$. $\square$

Now for the original problem: Let $S$ be a set of sequences such that every sequence of ontegers has a subsequence that is in $S$. If we pick a strictly  increasing sequence of integers, any subsequence will also be strictly increasing, and a strictly increasing sequence $x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots$ is a subsequence of a strictly  increasing sequence $y_1,y_2,y_3,\ldots$ if and only if $\{x_1,x_2,\ldots\}\subseteq \{y_1,y_2,\ldots\}$. Thus from the lemma, we conclude that $S$ is uncountable (already the strictly increasing sequences must be uncountably many).

Comment: By the way, you can even show that such a set has to have size of the continuum.

Comment: A little bit more details would be great. I don't understand part "Thus from the lemma, ..."

Comment: @Jonathan how exactly?

Comment: @panpan Given any real number $r$ define a sequence $\langle a_n  \rangle_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ so that $a_n$ codes the $n$'th decimal expansion of $r$ (for example using a bijection $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{Q}$). Then note that any subsequence of $\langle a_n  \rangle_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ uniquely determines $r$. But this means that for any real number you can pick a sequence in $S$ uniquely determining it. Such a map is injective.

Comment: @Jonathan could you post the full solution, I'm having troubles understanding this.

Comment: @panpan which part is unclear?

Comment: @Jonathan Why subsequence uniquely determinate r?

Comment: @panpan it obvious that it makes no difference if we consider sequences of integers or sequences of rationals, right (because there is a bijection between integers and rationals)? So simply pick $a_n$ to be the decimal expansion of $r$ up to the $n$'th digit (which is a rational number).

Comment: @panpan any subsequence of $\langle a_n \rangle$ also converges to the same real $r$.